# Wrapping search and cart in element Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml, header

I understand that in mage2 the header is generated through xml and knockout js, so all the blocks can be controlled with xml and the node - **move**

My question is i have the mini cart and search block in the header, they're called in by the fall back theme, the problem is I want to wrap the two separate **divs** in one container.

So instead of:

```
<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    // content
</div>
<div class="block block-search">
    // content
</div>
```

I want to generate the following:

```
<div class="block-wrapper-to-hold-the-items">
    <div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
        // content
    </div>
    <div class="block block-search">
        // content
    </div>
</div>
```

How do i go about doing this?

Comment: As both are different module. U have to start div tag in Search & End in Minicart respective .phtml files

Comment: Is that the only way to go about doing it? That feels very hacky :(

Comment: You are going to override those .phtml files in your Custom Theme. So it's don't hacky. U r overriding stuffs as per your need

Comment: Yes, but leaving unclosed div's isn't the best solution as another dev might not know what is going on and break things.

Comment: Definitely hacky and not a good way to do it. Try adding the wrapper xml & move elements somewhere else in your theme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think something like this would work, though I am often wrong :)

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <container name="block-wrapper-to-hold-the-items" as="block-wrapper-to-hold-the-items" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="block-wrapper-to-hold-the-items"/>
</referenceContainer>

<move element="minicart" destination="block-wrapper-to-hold-the-items"/>
<move element="top.search" destination="block-wrapper-to-hold-the-items"/>
```

Comment: Yes i thought this, but it didn't seem to move them, flushed the cache several times - but just didn't move them. I think this is on the right lines, but  im still not sure.

Comment: Maybe a `before="-"` or `after="-"` is required on the move elements?

Comment: Possibly, to put them one after the other. If my understanding is right, creating the container and then moving into it should work. But it doesnt :(

Comment: This worked a treat after i put it into the right file >_< haha thanks for the info. I knew i was on the right lines but this got me there (Y) thanks again.

Comment: This gives me an error. I am not sure if you can move an element inside a container you just created.